# A blockquote in a figure: When to use footer, when to use figcaption?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

There are two examples on the [w3.org's `blockquote`-page](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element):

**[Example 14](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#example-54bcdf6d)**:

```
<figure>
    <blockquote>
        "That monster custom, who all sense doth eat
        Of habit’s devil," <abbr title="et cetera">&c.</abbr> not in Folio

        "What a falling off was there !
        From me, whose love was of that dignity
        That it went hand in hand even with the vow
        I made to her in marriage, and to decline
        Upon a wretch."
    </blockquote>

    <footer>
        — <cite class="title">Shakespeare manual</cite>
        by <cite class="author">Frederick Gard Fleay</cite>,
        p19 (in Google Books)
    </footer>
</figure>
```

**[Example 19](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#example-7c6d3377)**:

```
<figure>
    <blockquote>
        <p>
            The truth may be puzzling. It may take some work to grapple with.
            It may be counterintuitive. It may contradict deeply held
            prejudices. It may not be consonant with what we desperately want to
            be true. But our preferences do not determine what’s true. We have a
            method, and that method helps us to reach not absolute truth, only
            asymptotic approaches to the truth — never there, just closer
            and closer, always finding vast new oceans of undiscovered
            possibilities. Cleverly designed experiments are the key.
        </p>
    </blockquote>

    <figcaption>
        <cite>Carl Sagan</cite>,
        in "<cite>Wonder and Skepticism</cite>",
        from the <cite>Skeptical Inquirer</cite> Volume 19, Issue 1 (January-February 1995)
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Both look very similar to me - content-wise. But they say *about the first one*:

> **Note**
>   In the example above, the citation is contained within the `footer` of a
>   `figure` element, this groups and associates the information, about the
>   quote, with the quote. The `figcaption` element was not used, in this case,
>   as a container for the citation as it is not a caption.

However, I don't understand the distinction between both versions. Can someone explain the difference and what's important to distinguish between `footer` and `figcaption`?

Comment: The example with the footer element appears in all versions of W3C HTML5, but not in the living spec. I wonder if it was there before, and then removed.

Comment: Also, this reminds me of [a similar discrepancy between W3C HTML5 and the living spec also pertaining to blockquote attribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429899/what-is-the-correct-way-to-mark-up-the-author-of-a-blockquote/19430032#19430032).

Comment: Are you interested specifically in W3C's take on this, or will any practical answer do? Though not from the W3C HTML WG, the living spec editor as well as others at W3C [think it doesn't matter](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1650), and frankly, I'm finding it very hard to make a case against not caring either.

Comment: Thanks for all the very interesting links regarding this issue, @BoltClock. Seems, I'm not the only one who's confused about it. Especially the last link to GitHub has a heated discussion. Actually I want to know, how to do it right semantically. I wrote a version that looked like "*Example 19*", then switched to W3C to see what they got and got confused about these two examples and the usage of a footer-element.

Comment: I actually think it's a very elegant distinction in terms of pure semantics. But for all practical level purposes, these kind of fine semantic distinctions are futile, since no HTML consumer is ever going to be able to rely on the use of one versus the other to extract meaning from it.

Comment: FWIW, the distinction is up to you. For *your* content, do you see the information about the quoted text as an integral part of the figure, or as an annotation of the figure. Use footer for the former, figcaption for the latter.

Comment: @Alohci That's some very good insight as well. Thanks. I think this would also be a valid second answer, when some references were added. What do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the following facts:

1. The non-normative examples in the W3C spec seem to contradict one another, as you've seen.
2. The W3C spec doesn't contain any *normative* text suggesting that either option is inappropriate. One of the *examples* claims that a citation is not a caption, but since it's not normative, you're well within your right to disagree.
3. From [this WHATWG issue](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1650), the living spec editor as well as a W3C CSSWG (i.e. not HTML WG) member think the difference doesn't matter in practice, though the former seems to lean towards `figcaption`.
4. In practice, most authors place attribution information in `figcaption` anyway, with no apparent repercussions.

... the conclusion seems to be that there is no meaningful or practical difference between the two, and that whichever you choose to use is a matter of personal preference.

Having said that, if you're still unable to decide, `figcaption` is more compatible with both specifications, not in terms of conformance (since `footer` and `figcaption` are *equally* conforming), but in terms of how they both describe its role and usage, especially with relation to the `figure` element (generally, you expect text associated with a figure to be its caption). Either way, what's *most* important are the `cite` elements, since ultimately they're the ones conveying attribution semantics, not their container element.

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer.